# How to load an objected by Id from the server into my Form Using Angular Template

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I am new to angular, so please forgive me if this question sounds a little bit off-key, but i am having problem understanding how to implement edit in this project.

After I click on the Edit link, I expect the Id to be sent to the  `EditEmployeeComponent.ts`

and here is my route

`{ path: 'edit/:id', component: EditEmployeeComponent },`

in `app.module.ts` and here is the anchor tag:

`<a class="btn" [routerLink]="['/edit/',emp.employeeId]" >Edit</a>`

**EditEmployeeComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../Services/employeeservice.service';
import { MyEmployees } from '../../Services/Employee';
import { Employee } from '../Employee/Employee';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from 
'@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 templateUrl: 'edit-employee.component.html'
})

export class EditEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
 errorMessage: string = '';
 public emps: Employees;
 employeeId: number;
 employeeForm: FormGroup;
 model = new Employee('', '');



 constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService, private _avRoute: 
  ActivatedRoute, private _fb: FormBuilder) {
   if (this._avRoute.snapshot.params['employeeId']) {
     this.employeeId = this._avRoute.snapshot.params["employeeId"];

  }
}

 ngOnInit(){
    if (this.employeeId > 0) {
      console.log(this.employeeId);
      this._employeeService.edit(this.employeeId)
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.emps = this._employeeService.employee
        } 
      , error => this.errorMessage = 'undefine property');
    }
}
```

here is also my **_employeeService class**

```
public edit(id) {
let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
return this._http.get('api/Employee/EditEmployeeGet?id=' + id, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
})
  .map((data: Employees) => {
    this.employee = data;
    return true;
  });
}
```

and this is the api Controller i send my request to **api/Employee/EditEmployee**

```
  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = 
  JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult EditEmployeeGet(int id)
    {
       var emp = _repo.GetEmployeeById(id);
        return Ok(emp);
    }
```

this is my **editEmployee.component.html**

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="">
       <div class="container">
         <h1>Edit Employee</h1>
         <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}} 
     </div>
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  #employeeForm="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="emps.employeeName" name="employeeName">
            <!--<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="name.invalid && formDir.submitted">
              Name is required.
            </span>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="city">City</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="emps.employeeCity" name="employeeCity">
            <!--<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="city.invalid && formDir.submitted">
              City is required
            </span>-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!employeeForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your router link change the code to this, the trailing '/' is not able to match with the route you defined:

```
[routerLink]="['/edit', emp.employeeId]"
```

Also in your component you have to get the params using `"id"`:

```
this._avRoute.snapshot.params['id']
```

But a better approach is to call the service in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook instead of the `constructor`. You need to subscribe to the Observable of the `ActivatedRoute.params` which will react to the change in the param in the URL.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Employee Details</h1>
             <div *ngIf="emps$ | async; let emps">
                  <h3> Id: {{emps.id}}</h3>
                  <h3> Name: {{emps.name}}</h3>
                  <h3> Age: {{emps.age}}</h3>
             </div>`,
  styles: [`h1, h3 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class EditEmployeeComponent   {

  emps$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private _empService: EmployeeService, private _avRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _fb: FormBuilder){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this._avRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.emps$ = this._empService.getEmployeeDetails(params['id']);
    });
  }
}
```

I have created a small demo for you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdvpzm

Comment: thanks for helping me understand were my mistake was. its working now.